# Custom Query Output Ordering with a CASE function

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by, case

I often find when I am pulling data for analysis, that I group the number of orders a customer has placed into ranges, such as:

1-2
3-5
6-9
10-12
13-15

I do this with a `CASE` function.  However, when you get the query results, the order ranges will be listed like:

1-2
10-12
13-15
3-5
6-9

This easy to correct in Excel when you have 1 query and a few order range groups.  However, when you're pulling many queries, it's a pain to correct this over and over.

What is the best way to pull a range and have it ordered correctly?

here's an example of the query I would write:

```
SELECT 
    OrderRange = CASE
        WHEN COUNT(OrderID) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN '1-5'
        WHEN COUNT(OrderID) BETWEEN 6 AND 10 THEN '6-10'
        WHEN COUNT(OrderID) > 10 THEN '10+'
        ELSE 'Error'
    END
FROM Orders
GROUP BY CASE
    WHEN COUNT(OrderID) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN '1-5'
    WHEN COUNT(OrderID) BETWEEN 6 AND 10 THEN '6-10'
    WHEN COUNT(OrderID) > 10 THEN '10+'
    ELSE 'Error'
    END
ORDER BY...  ?
```

Comment: You can't `GROUP BY ... COUNT`. Should the `GROUP BY` be something else? Also won't `ORDER BY  COUNT(OrderID)` work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd keep a table of ranges, e.g. (indices not written)

```
CREATE TABLE Ranges (RangeSet int, MinVal int, MaxVal int, Name varchar(50));
```

and then e.g.

```
INSERT INTO ranges VALUES
  (1,1,5,'1-5'),(1,6,10,'6-10'),(1,11,-1,'11+'),
  (2,1,10,'1-10'),(2,11,20,'11-20'),(2,21,30,'21-30'),(2,31,-1,'31+');
```

you get the idea. Now you do something like (table and field names free fiction)

```
SELECT
  CustomerID,
  count(OrderID) AS OrderCount
FROM Orders
WHERE <whatever, e.g order_date BETWEEN ... AND ...>
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING OrderCount>0
```

as you'd normally would expect, but wrap it in a superquery joining to the Ranges table

```
SELECT
  BaseView.CustomerID as CustomerID,
  Ranges.Name as OrderRange
FROM (
  SELECT
    CustomerID,
    count(OrderID) AS OrderCount
  FROM Orders
  WHERE <whatever, e.g order_date BETWEEN ... AND ...>
  GROUP BY CustomerID
  HAVING OrderCount>0
) AS BaseView
INNER JOIN Ranges ON
  Ranges.RangeSet=<id-of-required-rangeset>
  AND BaseView.OrderCount>=Ranges.MinVal
  AND (BaseView.OrderCount<=Ranges.MaxVal OR Ranges.MaxVal=-1)
ORDER BY RangeSet.MinVal DESC
;
```

Now you just have to supply the RangeSet you want to apply, maybe creating a new one on occasion.

Disclaimer: This is a performance-killer

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly you want the list of customers and order ranges ordered from least to highest.  You should be able to do that by just ordering by the count(orderID)

```
SELECT CustomerID,
    OrderRange = CASE
    WHEN COUNT(OrderID) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN '1-5'
    WHEN COUNT(OrderID) BETWEEN 6 AND 10 THEN '6-10'
    WHEN COUNT(OrderID) > 10 THEN '10+'
    ELSE 'Error'
END ,
FROM Orders
GROUP BY CustomerID
order by count(orderid)
```

Results:

```
CustomerId  OrderRange
CENTC   1-5
GROSR   1-5
LAZYK   1-5
...
ROMEY   1-5
VINET   1-5
ALFKI   6-10
CACTU   6-10
...
VICTE   6-10

WANDK   6-10
BLONP   10+
GREAL   10+
RICAR   10+
...
QUICK   10+
ERNSH   10+
SAVEA   10+
```